# How to sort a list of tuples by their first element?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
self.gridKeys = self.gridMap.keys() # The keys of the instance of the GridMap (It returns the product of every possible combination of positions in the specified grid, in tuples.)
print self.gridKeys
```

self.gridKeys:

```
[(7, 3), (6, 9), (0, 7), (1, 6), (3, 7), (2, 5), (8, 5), (5, 8), (4, 0), (9, 0), (6, 7), (5, 5), (7, 6), (0, 4), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 6), (8, 2), (4, 5), (9, 3), (6, 0), (7, 5), (0, 1), (3, 1), (9, 9), (7, 8), (2, 1), (8, 9), (9, 4), (5, 1), (7, 2), (1, 5), (3, 6), (2, 2), (8, 6), (4, 1), (9, 7), (6, 4), (5, 4), (7, 1), (0, 5), (1, 0), (0, 8), (3, 5), (2, 7), (8, 3), (4, 6), (9, 2), (6, 1), (5, 7), (7, 4), (0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 8), (3, 0), (2, 8), (9, 8), (8, 0), (6, 2), (5, 0), (1, 4), (3, 9), (2, 3), (1, 9), (8, 7), (4, 2), (9, 6), (6, 5), (5, 3), (7, 0), (6, 8), (0, 6), (1, 7), (0, 9), (3, 4), (2, 4), (8, 4), (5, 9), (4, 7), (9, 1), (6, 6), (5, 6), (7, 7), (0, 3), (1, 2), (4, 9), (3, 3), (2, 9), (8, 1), (4, 4), (6, 3), (0, 0), (7, 9), (3, 8), (2, 0), (1, 8), (8, 8), (4, 3), (9, 5), (5, 2)]
```

After sorting:

```
self.gridKeys = self.gridMap.keys() # The keys of the instance of the GridMap (It returns the product of every possible combination of positions in the specified grid, in tuples.)
self.gridKeys.sort() # They're dicts, so they need to be properly ordered for further XML-analysis.
print self.gridKeys
```

self.gridKeys:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
```

The first element of each tuple is the "x", and the second the "y". I'm moving objects in a list through iteration and using these keys (So, if I want to move something in the x axis, I have to go through all the column, and that might be causing a horrid problem that I'm not being able to solve).

How can I sort the tuples in this way?:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), ...]
```

Comment: But that's not sorting them by their first element, that's sorting by their *second* element, then their first. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I think OP meant `first element` to be `element at index 1`

Comment: I meant the first index of each tuple (Now I got a bit confused, but the final list down there is the "sorting" that I want to achieve).

Comment: `self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter of the `sort` function, to sort the tuples. The function of `key` parameter, is to come up with a value which has to be used to compare two objects. So, in your case, if you want the `sort` to use only the first element in the tuple, you can do something like this

```
self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

If you want to use only the second element in the tuple, then

```
self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

`sort` function will pass each and every element in the list to the lambda function you pass as parameter to `key` and it will use the value it returns, to compare two objects in the list. So, in your case, lets say you have two items in the list like this

```
data = [(1, 3), (1, 2)]
```

and if you want to sort by the second element, then you would do

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

First it passes `(1, 3)` to the lambda function which returns the element at index `1`, which is `3` and that will represent this tuple during the comparison. The same way, `2` will be used for the second tuple.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
import operator
self.gridKeys.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

While thefourtheye's solution is correct in the strict sense that it is exactly what you asked for in the title. It may not be actually what you want. It may be better to take it a bit farther via sorting by the reverse of the tuple instead.

```
self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x:tuple(reversed(x)))
```

This forces you to have an ordering like:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), ...]
```

Rather than having the first element be unordered like:

```
[(4, 0), (9, 0), (6, 0), (1, 0), (3, 0), ...]
```

Which is what I get when using:

```
self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

By default Python does a lexicographical sort from left to right. Reversing the tuple effectively makes Python do the lexicographical sort from right to left.

Comment: I found that his answer was not exactly what I wanted, but I've figured it out how to use it.. Using both [0] and [1].

self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
self.gridKeys.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

I'll analyze your version of it, thank you :).

Comment: I've found your version more elegant than using both [0] and [1], and I'm using it :).